# Travis cannot open my .ino sketch file

Tags: arduino, travis-ci

I'm trying to enable travis to build my arduino project.

What I'm able to:

- Download the CLI tools
- Execute the arduino command

What's not working:

- The arduino CLI keeps exiting with exit code 2. [3]

Relevant output of console:

```
$ arduino-1.5.2/./arduino --verify --board arduino:avr:uno HomeAutomation_Arduino/HomeAutomation_Arduino.ino
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx2048m -Xms512m
Can't open source sketch!
The command "arduino-1.5.2/./arduino --verify --board arduino:avr:uno HomeAutomation_Arduino/HomeAutomation_Arduino.ino" exited with 2.
```

[1] I've been following [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/continuous-integration-arduino-and-you/testing-your-project) guide.

[2] View the ENTIRE console log [here](https://travis-ci.org/dakshsrivastava/HomeAutomation/builds/361118638)

[3] Arduino exit codes : [here](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/build/shared/manpage.adoc#exit-status)

Comment: You messed up your second link. We need a link to the problematic Travis CI build.

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed, please check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some versions of the Arduino IDE do not support relative paths to the sketch. 1.5.2 is one of these. You must specify the full path to the sketch, in this case:

```
"${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/HomeAutomation_Arduino/HomeAutomation_Arduino.ino"
```

You should note you are more likely to run into these sorts of quirks when using very old versions of the Arduino IDE. 1.5.2 was the very first to support CLI usage and thus likely to have more than its fair share of these and also is missing some features of later IDE versions.

Comment: I tried giving the full path in one of the iterations, but I guess I encountered a separate error and erroneously removed it. Thanks! It works! I'm stuck with an older SDK since later version give an entirely separate error that I could not find a solution for. Thanks for this! :)